# PowerShell: The try statement is missing its catch or Finally block

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I am trying to make a try statement with a foreach loop. Everything I look up shows this code should be right but for some reason it says

`The try statement is missing its catch or Finally block`
I have 0 idea why this is happening I made sure ALL { and } match up. Even if I take this out of the foreach loop, the try catches do not work.

```
Clear-Host
Clear-Content .\PS.txt
$args1 = Get-Content .\names.txt
$args1 = $args1.Split(",")
$ArrComputers =  $args1

$i = 0
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) 
{
 $Computer = $Computer.Trim(" ")

    try{
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        

        "PASS " + $Computer +'|'
        $HDDInfo = ""
        $getIP, $computerSystem, $computerCPU, $hdds, $computerOS, $OS  = " "
        $i +=1
        $z = 0
        [string]$hdd = ""
        $getIP =[string](Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet).IPAddress
        $myOBJ = "" | Select-Object "computer"
        $computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer
        $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer
        $hdds = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter drivetype=3
        $computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Computer
        $OS = $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
            write-host "System Information for: " $computerSystem.Name -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
            "CPU: " + $computerCPU.Name
            foreach ($computerhdd in $hdds) { 
                $z +=1
                If($z -eq 1){
                $PRHDDName = [string]$computerhdd.DeviceID
                } else {
                    $SECHDDName = [string]$computerhdd.DeviceID
                }

                $HDDInfo = [string]($HDDInfo+"<"+$computerhdd.DeviceID+">" + "HDD Capacity/" + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB" )
                "HDD Drive Letter: " + $HDDInfo
            [string]$hdd = ([string]($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + [string]"," + [string]$hdd)
            }
            "RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
            "OS: " + $OS
        
        
            $temp = [string]$myOBJ.computer
            [string]$myOBJ.computer = [string]("| !" + $Computer + ".! , +" + $getIP + '.+, a[' + $computerCPU.Name + ".] , ~" + $HDDInfo+ " ~, {" + $OS + ".} a|") 
            Add-Content .\PS.txt $myOBJ.computer
    } 
     #End of try
        catch[System.UnauthorizedAccessException]{
        Add-Content .\PS.txt "| Failed |"
        
    }catch{
        Add-Content .\PS.txt "| Failed |"
        "FAIL" + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
    }


}
```

Comment: Add a space between `catch` and `[System.UnauthorizedAccessException]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a space missing between "catch" and "[System.UnauthorizedAccessException]"